# access all php array rows using mysql limit clause

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Using following method with MySQL query limit clause, if I try to access array values using foreach loop, then it display only limited rows inside **$query_data** array as per LIMIT clause.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
{
    $query_data[] = $row;   
}
```

array **$query_data** contains 8 rows result-set. if LIMIT clause of query is set to 0,3 then it will display only 3 records array values.

is there any way to fetch all records ignoring limit clause every time at any place using foreach or any other loop?

Answer (score 1):

No. The `LIMIT` clause means the data is not fetched. If you wish to fetch the additional data, you must get rid of the `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: So is there any way to handle pagination without limit clause?

Comment: Not unless you do something like... "WHERE id BETWEEN :start AND :end".

I don't understand what you're trying to do, but you can also do something like... `LIMIT 10,10` to start at the 10th element.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime your dealing with pagination you must use the LIMIT clause otherwise your site wont know what to do. From what i'm understanding is that you don't know how to use the limit clause. Think of it as Limit $starting_point, $ending_point.  so if my  starting point is 100 and ending point is 200 then the query will begin at record 100 and end at record 200 so it will display 100 records in total. There is another way. If  you remove the limit clause and show all records you can use this jQuery library to do the pagination for you. [Jquery Quick Pagination](http://www.sitepoint.com/demos/jquery-quick-pagination/) . But if you have alot of records then it will significantly slow the page load down.

Comment: Thanks Sarmen for your inputs but I do know about MYSQL limit clause. I had a different problem here for which I had different solution in my mind, which also suggested by Tordek  in 1st reply. (run same query twice without limit clause & create new array containing all values). Whole purpose of asking this question was to reduce no of database instances, which failed here by opting to run two same queries (one for pagination values & another for faceted like search output showing complete query output).

Comment: Thanks Sarmen for sharing Jquery Quick pagination but as you mentioned, lots of records will slow down page load. it will not work for me. i' am working on job portal where lots of job openings will be searched by multiple users at a time. I'am expecting results between 2 lac to 5 lac. Will this work for that much data?

Comment: you can try it and see how slow the page loads, if its ok then you can just use it.